# docker-composer.yml not work properly

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I made a docker-composer.yml because it's cleaner.

From these commands below:

`docker run -d  -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro  -v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro  -e POSTGRES_USER=rundeck  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=rundeck --name rundeck_db postgres:9.4.5`

`docker run --rm -ti -p 192.168.59.103:4440:4440 --link rundeck_db:db --name rundeck 3a34fdafc98a`

To:

```
rundeck_db:
    image: postgres:9.4.5
    environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: rundeck
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: rundeck
    volumes:
        - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
        - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"

rundeck:
    build: .
    ports:
        - "192.168.59.103:4440:4440"
    links:
        - rundeck_db:db
```

And Dockerfile is

```
FROM mbopm/ubuntu-oracle-java:2.0

# install rundeck
RUN wget -O /opt/rundeck.deb http://dl.bintray.com/rundeck/rundeck-deb/rundeck-2.6.1-1-GA.deb && \
    dpkg -i /opt/rundeck.deb && \
    rm -rf /opt/rundeck.deb /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# change base configuration
RUN mkdir /etc/service/rundeck && \
    mkdir /var/lib/rundeck/.ssh && \
    chown -R rundeck:rundeck /var/lib/rundeck

# add init and startup scripts
ADD assets/run/rundeck.sh /etc/service/rundeck/run
ADD assets/startup/* /etc/my_init.d/

# http, https
EXPOSE 4440

# project files
# configs
# ssh-keys
# logs
VOLUME [ "/var/rundeck", "/etc/rundeck", "/var/lib/rundeck/.ssh", "/var/log/rundeck" ]
```

Suddenly it doesn't function. (Postgres works, but Rundeck doesn't.)

Also `docker ps` says

[image]

`COMMAND` part should be `/sbin/my_init` instead of `/bin/sh -c ./run.sh`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
CMD [ "/sbin/my_init" ]
```

at the end of your dockerfile in order to change the `COMMAND` part

Answer (score 1):

you can also add command to you docker-compose.yml file

`rundeck:
    build: .
    command: /sbin/my_init
    ports:
        - "192.168.59.103:4440:4440"
    links:
        - rundeck_db:db`